# How to show Toast messages from a thread in another class

Tags: android, multithreading, toast, android-runonuithread

I'm developing an app and I need to show a Toast message from a Thread that runs in another class. 
I Read about runOnUiThread but it doesn't works.. In main activty there is a call to another java class and here there is the connection to a webserver and I handle Http's messages from the server. Here, if I got 204 messages I need to show a toast. How can I implement runOnUiThread?

Thanks

Comment: you don't implement it, it's already ready to use

Comment: Do you aware with _interface_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your activity's reference to that worker class and call the *runOnUiThread* like this

```
 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Your Message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I understood my fault: in my class I was trying to call my activity context but I didn't passed the reference... So passed the reference, it works.. 

Thanks and sorry for the wasting of time!!!

Comment: @Yoshi No problem. Accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library. It handles all thread stuff for you and you don't have to re-invent wheel.

```
//make request in ui thread
yourService.getMyData().enqueue(new Callback<YourResponse>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<YourResponse> response) {
        //handle responses in ui thread
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
           //Toast.makeText()..

        } else {
            //error
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
       //toast the error
    } 

});
```

Beautiful, right?